# PDO PHP Fetch Class

Tags: php, pdo

I am learning pdo in php , so as to make database access easier and more efficient .One explanation i have read for fetch _class is that  The properties of your object are set BEFORE the constructor is called.What does this mean? Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PDO::FETCH_CLASS with Magic Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898794/using-pdofetch-class-with-magic-methods)

Comment: See here how you can have universal setters and getters in PHP on an empty class:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6605378/584490

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This means that when using PDO to return a result into a custom object, you are required to set out the member variables which correspond to the query result keys.

such as:

```
class User
{
    //Predefine Here
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $email;
    public $hash;

    public function profileLink()
    {
         return sprintf('<a href="/profile/%s">%s</a>',$this->id,$this->username);
    }
}

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");
foreach($result as $user)
{
    echo $user->profileLink();
}
```

This way PDO can set the variables to the object outside of its internal scope.

if your user class was like so:

```
class User
{
}
```

then PDO Would not be able to set the values from outside the scope, as there are no properties defined.

Comment: And I am guessing this means if you setup your class with getters and setters, private vars, you can't use PDO::FETCH_CLASS ?

Comment: I think getters and setters should get invoked fine (untested)

Comment: Yes you can still use private vars. FETCH_CLASS will assign results to private variables.

Comment: @RobertPitt - take a look at PDO::FETCH_LAZY constant as well re: getters/setters - as the columns are found they're assigned respectively.  I'm sure there's a performance hit as it's all dynamic and it's better to KNOW what you're querying / asking for in advance for others to use your D.R.Y. code as an API later.

Comment: as @Kris pointed out they don't have to be public. I don't think they have to be declared at all, so your second example of just declaring the class would work fine. Its obviously not suggested since it makes your code useless to view, but it works.

Answer (score 36):

Say you have this snippit of code

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = 1;
    }
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT bar FROM foo");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Foo'); 
$stmt->execute();
$obj = $stmt->fetch()
?>
```

The bar propery for $obj will be set to "1" not what is retreived from the database.

If you would like it to be set to the result from the database instead of "1" you can change the fetch mode to

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Foo');
```

This causes the constructor to be called before assigning the results to the properties

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using: `FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'classname')`
You can use: `fetchObject('classname')`

Example:

```
class Car extends DatabaseTable {

const TABLE_NAME = 'cars';

// Table Columns
private $color;
private $brand;
private $type;

public function __construct($pdo, $id = false)
{
    parent::__construct($pdo, TABLE_NAME, $id);
}

public static function getAll($pdo, $order = 'id') {
    $query =   'SELECT * FROM ' . self::TABLE_NAME . ' 
                ORDER BY ' . $order;

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

    $objects = [];
    while ($obj = $statement->fetchObject(self::class, [$pdo])) {
        $objects[$obj->getId()] = $obj;
    }
    return $objects;
}
```

The parent Constructor just sets its 3 properties like: `$this->id = $id;`

Answer (score 2):

Looking back at PDO::FETCH_CLASS, you don't really need to define the variables as public nor private (as of PHP 7.0 ) , you could define an empty class and PHP PDO will populate the attributes as $Class->attribute even if they are not defined.

this is very useful because you can reuse classes with multiple queries that treat the same table but might return different columns

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that setting/getting an instance's properties is a lot slower in PHP if you're doing it on a class that doesn't define the property in question versus one that does (I can't currently find the link though).  If dealing with a huge amount of such objects the performance impact could be significant.  Plus may IDEs have type-hinting facilities that would not function without a defined property.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but if someone else reads it: _"but might return different columns"_ - That's a massive anti pattern. When you get a class, you should know what properties it has or you would need to make a bunch of `property_exists()` and similar all over your code.