# stop generting member variables which does not exist with PDO::FETCH_CLASS

Tags: php, pdo

when we use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` its creates member variable of specified class with public scope. How to prevent this default behavior and stop creating those public members?

```
class user
{
/**
Table user has
id int PK
name UNIQUE
password
*/
protected $id;
protected $name;
/*more code.......*/
}

 $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'user');
 $user=$stmt->fetch();
```

now if i `var_dump()` $user it has 'password' public property. which i want to prevent

Comment: Create the items in question as private members and the values will not be populated, but I suspect this is not what you want. It may also cause PDO to throw an exception, not checked. I suspect the answer to this is "you can't" and you'll just have to live with it. I'd be happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: Somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class which mentions private members too

Comment: @Cups Interestingly that question seems to suggest that what this question is asking how to avoid won't happen anyway. I'm testing now to see what it really does.

Comment: I have updated my post to clarify the problem

Comment: @user1538127 I see (and have repeated) the problem. This might be an obvious point, but can't you just not include the fields you don't want in the field list for the query? Aside from that I can think of a slightly ugly work around, but I think just not getting the data you don't want in the first place would be the best solution.

Comment: @Cups Not only does this "problem" definitely exist, but pre-defining the relevant members `private` doesn't even work - they still get populated. The other question you linked, it appears is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can find to this that I would consider acceptable (and I still don't really *like* it) is to set the fetch mode to `PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` and define an empty `__set()` method - or at least, one that doesn't set the properties if they don't exist.

So to show you based on your code above:

```
class user {

  protected $id;
  protected $name;

  public function __set ($name, $val) {
    if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
      $this->$name = $val;
    }
  }

}

$stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'user');
$user=$stmt->fetch();
```

This does *work* but as I say I don't *like it*, mainly in your example because it allows the `protected` properties to be set from the outside, and in order to circumvent this you start having to do horrible things creating extra properties to indicate locking and all sorts of nonsense like that.