# Receiving mail using Bottle on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, bottle

I'm new to programming. I'm using Bottle on GAE. I want to receive and read mails (if it's possible).

This is my app.yaml file:

```
- url: /_ah/mail/contact@appid.appspotmail.com
  script: main.py
  login: admin

inbound_services:
- mail
```

This is (should be) my mail handler in the main.py file:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler

@route('/_ah/mail/contact@appid.appspotmail.com', method = 'POST')
def receive_mail():
    pass
```

When I send an  email to the above address in logs appears:

```
 2012-09-03 17:03:00.878 /_ah/mail/contact@appid.appspotmail.com 200 187ms 0kb  
 0.1.0.20 - - [03/Sep/2012:07:03:00 -0700] "POST /_ah/mail/contact@appid.appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 59
```

How can I read/parse the mail?

Thank you in advance for any answer or comment.

Comment: PLEASE REFRAIN FROM POINTLESS EDITING.

Comment: Why 'POINTLESS'? It does no harm. It only makes answers and questions look more clean and clear, especially for the beginners.

Comment: In the edit help section it reads: "Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
Some common reasons to edit are: to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes, to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it" etc. And only "single character"/"tiny"/"trivial" edits are discouraged.

Comment: `And only "single character"/"tiny"/"trivial" edits` - that's what are you doing exactly.

Comment: If you think that question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class) looks clearer and cleaner after you rollbacked it to the initial version, then I won't bother with editing anymore.(And it wasn't a "single character" edit: it improved the formatting and the spelling/grammar).

Comment: Come on, all you added is just pointless decorations. Without them it boils down to a single character edit.

Comment: Maybe it was not much of an edit, but surely it was better and cleaner than your rollbacked version. So I don't see the reason you rollbacked it (after it passed the peer review) and I don't see the reason of downvoting a question which has nothing to do with the editing stuff. You could only tell me about "pointless editing" and I'd keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to decode the POST body using `mail.InboundEmailMessage` like in [`webapp.InboundMailHandler`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/mail_handlers.py&q=InboundMailHandler%20package%3agoogleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=65)

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

@route('/_ah/mail/contact@appid.appspotmail.com', method = 'POST')
def receive_mail():
    message = mail.InboundEmailMessage(request.body)
    logging.info("received email from: %s" % message.sender)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works! (btw, it's a typo in your answer: are missing the closing double quotes)