# fetchAll with PDO::FetchClass returning same object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

### What I'm doing

I'm attempting to get an array of Image objects using the following:

(If I run the raw MySQL query, I am returned 3 distinct rows, all with different values, except for the `product_id`, obviously.)

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `j_images` WHERE product_id = :product_id';
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare($query);
if($stmt)
{
    $I = new \jenis\Product\Image();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $I);
    $result = $stmt->execute(array('product_id'=>$product_id));

    if($result)
    {
        $images = $stmt->fetchAll();
        var_dump($images);
    }
}
```

## What I Get

An array with 3 `jenis\Product\Image` objects, but the objects (including references) are identical.

## What I expect

An array with 3 `\jenis\Product\Image` objects, each unique.

Is this because it is fetching into the same object (i.e. `$I`)? If so, is there a way around this?

However [Example 4](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-955) in the PHP documentation would lead me to believe that this is possible.

If I follow the example directly from the documentation:

`$images = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "\jenis\Product\Image");`, I get three separate objects, but all properties are `NULL`.

## Additional Information

Here is a stripped down version of my Image Class:

```
namespace jenis\Product;

use jenis\DB as DB;
use \PDO as PDO;
class Image
{
    public $id;
    public $product_id;
    public $url;

    public static function getImagesByProduct($product_id)
    {
        … code outlined above … 
    }
}
```

The code outlined above is executed as a static method (e.g. `Image::getImagesByProduct($product_id);`

Comment: Remove the `fetchAll` line and just `var_dump($I);`

Comment: @Digital Chris - that returns an Image object with properties corresponding to the first record.

Comment: Do you get the correct results if you remove the `setFetchMode()`?

Comment: @Digital Chris - thanks for the help; yes, I get the correct results, albeit as a `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` type of array. I may just go this route if I can't figure it out.

Comment: The issue may be your Image class... check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class . PDO may not be able to access the vars?

Comment: @DigitalChris I wondered about that as well, but all of the necessary variables are publicly accessible and declared at the start of the class (I'll edit to include this information) The above is run as a static method within the Image class, but I wouldn't think that would be an issue.

Comment: @Digital Chris - you were right.  When adding `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` to the fetchInto method, everything worked as I would expect, because I allow assignment by passing variables to the constructor.  Please feel free to note this as the answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this wasn't working was because I had developed my constructor so that optional parameters could be passed.

For example:

```
function __construct($name='', $description='')
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->description=$description;
}
```

Because the constructor is utilized when `FETCH_CLASS` is called, this was causing my variables to be `NULL`, as the properties are not passed as parameters.  As @Digital Chris noted, I needed `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` which allowed the properties to be set after the constructor was called.