# PHP Returning array of objects from rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want the php to be able to load all the rows in the table into an object each and then add them all to an array and return the array to be converted into java objects etc.

```
<?php


ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "Example";
$dbuser     = "Example";
$dbpass     = "Example";

 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$objectArray = array();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
  {
    #add all columns on this row to an object and add to array
  }
$stmt->execute();

if(!$stmt)
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`

```
$array = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) 
{
    #add all columns on this row to an object and add to array
    $array[] = $row; // $row is an object now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also fetch results into a defined class.

Read this reply: [PDO PHP Fetch Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class)