# how PDO::FETCH_CLASS work without passing class name as argument

Tags: php, pdo

i am trying to understand why is this method i have works without me passing class name to the fetch statement. the method  looks like this:

```
  function getAll() {
    $DBH = $this->getDbh();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ads";
    try {
      $STH = $DBH->query($query);
      $ads = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      Slim::getInstance()->log->error($e);
    }

    return $ads;
  }
```

i tried looking for an answer/example in the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) but still can't understand how the FETCH_CLASS knows or from where it deduced what is the class name...any guidance plz?

Comment: What do you understand under `working`?

Comment: What did it return? What's the output of `var_dump($ads)`?

Comment: array of objects of the correct type (ad)

Comment: Do you have any previous call to `$DBH->setFetchMode()`?

Comment: no..i have following ones like this one for example : `      $rules = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'AdRule');`

Comment: I really can't think of how PDO would know to use the `Ad` class if you didn't instruct it to. Are you using an application framework that may be injecting some magic into the `getDbh()` method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class