# Foreach Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach, notice

```
<?php

include "baglan.php";
class Dizi {    

public function dizis(){
    return $this->dizi;
}
}
$query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM diziler ");
$query2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'link');

foreach($query2 as $row){
    echo $row;
    break;
}


?>
```

I think I did everything right but I receive error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dizimag\new.php on line 14
>
> Array

Tried everything but I guess I do something wrong with foreach but I couldn't find it anywhere.

```
 class Uye {

  public function adsoyad(){
    return $this->uye_ad . ' ' . $this->uye_soyad;
  }

  public function rutbe(){
  if ( $this->uye_rutbe == 1 )
     return 'Yönetici';
  else
     return 'Üye';
}

}

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM uyeler");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Uye');

foreach ( $query as $row ){
print $row->adsoyad() . ': ' . $row->rutbe() . '<br />';
}
```

this code works perfect. Where did i make mistake? i did same things ? :S

Comment: Which line is line 14?

Comment: `$row` is an object of class `link`.

Comment: What does `class Dizi` have to do with this? Did you mean to use `Dizi` instead of `link` in `setFetchMode`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class

Answer (score 1):

You receive the `Array to string conversion` error because PDO is returning `$row` as an array in line 14:

```
foreach($query2 as $row){
    echo $row; // <- this is an array, echo'ing it will fail
    break;
}
```

To learn how to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS, I suggest that you study the examples given here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
- [PDO PHP Fetch Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class)