# create new object php and insert mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The goal is:

```
    A POST request to this script should create a new company object and thus 
    a new row in the company table and associated company address table.
```

Currently I have the insert working properly with the following:

```
$randomname="1";
$randomdescription="Bill is going to work at this company";
$randomad="123 Main Street";
$randomad2="N/A";
$randomcity="Cincinnati";
$randomstate="Ohio";
$randomzip="45205";
$completedesc=$randomname." ". $randomdescription." ".$randomad." ". $randomad2." ".$randomcity." ".$randomstate." ".$randomzip;
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO company (name, description)
    VALUES ('$randomname', '$completedesc')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
   $data= "New record created successfully";
   $data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   echo $data;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
     $data= "company error". $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
   $data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   echo $data;
    }
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO company_address (company_id, address,address_2,city,state,zip)
    VALUES ('$randomname','$randomad','$randomad2','$randomcity','$randomstate','$randomzip')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
   $data= "New record created successfully into company address";
   $data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   echo $data;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
   $data= "company address error". $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();;
   $data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   echo $data;
    }
```

The problem that I am struggling with the most is the "create a new company object". Right now I do not believe my code is using an object. Is there an easy way to make an object so I can perform the insert.

Comment: Step 1: learn to use prepared statements with PDO. What you are doing now will get you slapped by your teacher (I assume it is a homework, but since you are actually writing the code yourself, it OK).

Comment: Step 2: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137051/pdo-php-fetch-class .. I think that's what was mean in the assignment (though, I would not recommend this approach - it would be better to manually wire the data from the select in the proper *setter* for you `Company` class).

Comment: could you provide a brief example of what you mean by manually wire the data from the select? Write now I am printing two separate JSON encodes and getting  JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character