# Get from PDO class with class based by FK

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, foreign-keys

I am using PDO for getting data from database. I have entities (classes with getters and setters) and Repository what are getting data from daatbase like I have a class *Account* and using SELECT in *AccountRepository* and it returns Account object (thanks to PDO and it's `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Account::class)`).

But in database in table *accounts* I have also a foreign key (Currency_id) to class *Currency*. How can I get these two classes combined to some object using PDO, so I can use something like $Account->getCurrency()->getName().

Only solution what came to my mind is to get raw data from database using combined select and write own data mapper for new object called like AccountCurrencyCombined. Is it the only solution? What I want to get more complex SQL select where I will use more entities. Do I really have to write my own mapper for every select? Thank you.

Comment: as yu can see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10962439/5193536 you nned there a SELECT with inner join and you have to adept the class to the new columns

Comment: Not happening with `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` for starters, it's rather limited when you actually get your hands dirty. You're better off fetching an array and feeding it into your class/object. You could have a receiver/aggregator object that 1. is fed the data along with info on the tables, 2. looks up the tables@objects correlations, and 3. creates objects specific for the data and hosts/returns them. You wouldn't need to specify each possible combination separately, but you'd have to have their individual specifications available to your aggregator object.

Comment: That's a fair question but the answer is anything but simple. What you're looking for is called ORM and your best bet is to use an existing one.