# Doctrine and Symfony fetch object from raw sql query

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have question about this one case:
Can I fetch object Executor which have relation to Application and this application is a require parameter in Executor construct?

```
 public function findExecutorToRun()
{
    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

    $sql = "
    SELECT e.*
    FROM executor e
    join application a on e.application_id = a.id
    where
          a.status = 'prod'  and
          e.last_execution_time is null or
          ((e.last_execution_time + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE <= now()) and e.period = 'minutes') or
          ((e.last_execution_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR <= now()) and e.period = 'hourly') or
          ((e.last_execution_time + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= now()) and e.period = 'daily') or
          ((e.last_execution_time + INTERVAL 1 WEEK <= now()) and e.period = 'weekly') or
          ((e.last_execution_time + INTERVAL 1 MONTH <= now()) and e.period = 'monthly')
    ORDER BY FIELD(e.period,'all','monthly','weekly', 'daily', 'hourly', 'minutes')
    limit 1;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    // returns an array of arrays (i.e. a raw data set)
    return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Executor::class);
}
```

After run this script i got this obvious error: `Too few arguments to function App\\Entity\\Executor::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected`

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use raw sql not even dql or query builder?

Comment: cause i never found information how to use this order -> ORDER BY FIELD in DQL or QueryBuilder.

Comment: You can use a `CASE` statement in DQL instead of using "FIELD" method of Mysql

Comment: hmm and how this CASE can help me? im confused

Comment: I am not sure but  i think you need to change the `Executor::class` to `"Executor"` . See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50854397/12042800) for more .