# php - Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function PostManager::__construct()

Tags: php

Hi guys I'm new to php and there is something weird I don't understand.
All the functions inside the class is working.

But now I want to get this information when I create new instance

I try to add __construct and use the same functions but it get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function PostManager::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 2 expected
```

The thing is that if I try to echo/var_dump the values from the __construct its working. I did find around stackoverflow some results but nothing really helpful for my case or I just understood it wrong. I used both static:: and self:: but got the same results. please let me know if I need to add more info.

the files :

index.php :

```
<?php
require "Curl.php";
require "Proccessor.php";
require "User.php";
require "PostManager.php";
$conn = require 'db.php';

// this is work $post = PostManager::getPostInfo($conn, 3); 
   // **this is not work** $post = new PostManager($conn, 3);
```

PostManager.php :

```
<?php
class PostManager
{
    public $postId;
    public $conn;
    public function __construct($conn, $postId)
    {

        $this->postId = $postId;
        $this->conn = $conn;
       //here I get the error =>  static::getPostById($conn, $postId);
        
    }

    public static function getPostInfo($conn, $postId)
    {
        $post = static::getPostById($conn, $postId);
        $user = User::getByID($conn, $post->user_id);
        $comments = static::getCommentsByUserID($conn, $post->id);
        $post_info = (object) ["post" => $post, "user" => $user, "comments" => $comments];
        return $post_info;
    }

    public static function getPostById($conn, $id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT post.*
              FROM post
              WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'PostManager');
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return $stmt->fetch();
        }
    }

    public static function getCommentsByUserID($conn, $postId)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT comment.*
      FROM comment
      WHERE post_id = :post_id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':post_id', $postId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'PostManager');
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return $stmt->fetch();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: __construct() function will be executed automatically upon calling member functions. You don't have to call it manually.

Comment: What do you think is the result of `$conn = require 'db.php';`, what does `$conn` get set to? (`Require` returns 1 if successful, error if not; and `include` returns `false` and gives a warning if not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'PostManager', array($conn, $postId));
```

You forgot to pass the parameters here.

This is the signature you wanna use:

```
public PDOStatement::setFetchMode(int $mode = PDO::FETCH_CLASS, string $class, ?array $constructorArgs): bool
```

As you can see if the Ctor has args then you need to pass them as another parameter
`array $constructorArgs`

Comment: thanks for the comment. 
I tried use the first part :
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'PostManager', array($conn, $postId));
but the app is just crushing.

the second part :
public PDOStatement::setFetchMode(int $mode = PDO::FETCH_CLASS, string $class, ?array $constructorArgs): bool

Im not quit sure how to use this sorcery. 
I will look it up.

Comment: @YanivCode The 2nd part is just the signature from the manual. The first part will work, but maybe you have more problems with your code.

Comment: Maybe. However without creating new Instance its work great that's what is confusing me

Comment: The fetch class is there to fetch all the fields from the query as a result. You don't need a fetch class. If you use a fetch class you should give it all the fields that are in the result set of the query you're executing. Like: `$id`, `$postName` or whatever columns your db query has. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137083/11808788

Comment: Thanks @Charles. I will check this out thanks a lot.

Comment: oh It did help ! Solved !